# Firebase Authentication on wordpress website

Tags: php, android, wordpress, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a wordpress website and an android WebView app to access that website. On the app somehow, I have integrated firebase Authentication for Facebook and Google . And, as for the wordpress website it has its own Authentication system so, what I want to achieve is when a user registers through the app using firebase Auth system the user should also be registered on the wordpress Authentication database so that they can access or login into the wordpress website and access it. Is there a way to achieve this? Or if not, what would be the best way to let user register to the website using the app. I think I am missing something here because of my very little knowledge. But, I would be happy if someone could point me a way on how to achieve something as this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use WordPress' [JSON API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#create-a-user) to register users.

Comment: can u be a little more specific?? :/

Answer (score 2):

By the time the user register through firbase Auth system and get the response, your app should send the registerred user info to the register api offerred by wordpress to register this user in wordpress system. You also need to look into the implementation of wordpress function `wp_set_auth_cookie` to mock the login cookie for clients, the cookie value may be part of your wordpress register api's response. After getting the cookie value, android need to manipulate the cookie and save the cookie to webview in order to auto login to wordpress admin backend system.

Comment: @akang-toshi  can you comment if this worked ok? Were the comments above enough to get it working ? I am looking to do the same thing. Users login in the app with FirebaseAuth and when they select a link to visit my Wordpress site they would be authorized with previous App Firebase Authentication and avoid a second login screen prompt at the wordpress site.

Comment: @Nexu7_2012 Sorry it should have worked but, I was unable to do it. Instead I removed the firebase authentication system from the app and used the wordpress login screen in the starting page of the app.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that helps Firebase users to log in to the WordPress site. Here is the official documentation: https://firebase-wordpress-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auth/wordpress-user-integration.html

Basically what it does is when you log in through FirebaseUI Web, it will create a user in WordPress and log you into WordPress dashboard.

Comment: The link you shared doesn't work but,thanks for the answer as i have now know that there is a plugin available for it.