# Is it possible to sync a user from a MERN stack app with a Wordpress site?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, express, mern

Ok, so I have a Web Application that is built on the MERN stack(FE uses React and BE uses Express). I have a separate site that is built on WordPress that will be used as a knowledgebase/help desk site. The WordPress site currently is used used to have documentation articles, so it is not a problem, but later on, we would like to integrate a ticket system, as well as a forum. The main goal will be to use it for users to have a wide array of places to either get their problems fixed or to find a solution.

So based on that, is there a possibility to sync WordPress users with a MERN Web Application?

Comment: Your best bet is to use a third party authentication API for both. Something like [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) would work well.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - How will that help with globalizing one single login for the WebApp and the Wordpress site? Or is there a plugin on Wordpress to be able to login via Firebase?

Comment: Hmmm...that wasn't a hard lookup at all !! - https://wordpress.org/plugins/firebase-authentication/

Comment: and details - https://wordpress.org/plugins/firebase-authentication/

Comment: And stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43781435/firebase-authentication-on-wordpress-website

Comment: And another - https://github.com/dalenguyen/firebase-wordpress-plugin

Comment: Wow - did you even try to find anything?